# Macbook air, mavericks, installing ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install ruby 1.9.3-p392 via rvm on Macbook Air (fresh Mavericks installation). If anyone knows how long does it take? It has taken more than hour than it started and I only see the output:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.....
Installing required packages: gcc46.\
```

Any progress, only the whole system really slow down. I'm not sure if it should take so long.

Comment: I've just installed Ruby 2.1.1 and it took 5 minutes (using [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install))

Comment: Yes, I've also installed ruby 2.1.1 first and it took 2 or three minutes. But ruby 1.9.3-p392 needs to install gcc46 and I want to know is it normal that is still installing.

Answer (score 0):

create a different user account and run it under there. I had the same issue on my mac pro it took forever and failed and this solved it. also http://railsinstaller.org/en was failing but on the new user account it worked like a charm. I think it had something to do with the environment on the old user account because i had alot of things set up for java development.

this solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It turns out that it may take a lot of time to compile gcc. I don't now how much it took for me as I just left my laptop working all night, but it did its work. I have finally installed ruby 1.9.3. This is an issue on rvm repo about this: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2742